# SUMPRODUCT with multiple ORs (+), doublecounting

Tags: excel

From my understanding you can use " + " as a way to include OR criteria within a SUMPRODUCT formula. However there is an issue with my formula.

I've attempted to insert an OR criteria within the formula, outlined below:

Loan Type = Other .... or Loan Type = HELOC .... or Lock Date = ""

This formula brings back 10,240

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Loan Type]="Other")+(Table1[Loan Type]="HELOC")+(Table1[LOCK DATE]=""), --(Table1[DPA] <> "Y"),--(Table1[Disbursement Date]=Daily!$E36),--(Table1[CLOSING DATE] > 1), --(Table1[Run Date] > E36),--ISERROR(SEARCH("Jumbo",(Table1[Loan Program]))), Table1[Total Loan Amount])
```

This formula brings back 5,120

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Loan Type]="Other")+(Table1[LOCK DATE]=""), --(Table1[DPA] <> "Y"),--(Table1[Disbursement Date]=Daily!$E36),--(Table1[CLOSING DATE] > 1), --(Table1[Run Date] > E36),--ISERROR(SEARCH("Jumbo",(Table1[Loan Program]))), Table1[Total Loan Amount])
```

The only difference is the OR (+) criteria at the beginning of the formula. The first formula is incorrectly double counting (there is only one instance in the whole dataset with a loan amount of 5,120). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your OR conditions in the [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sign-function-109c932d-fcdc-4023-91f1-2dd0e916a1d8) so that two or more positives do not return more than 1.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((Table1[Loan Type]="Other")+(Table1[Loan Type]="HELOC")+(Table1[LOCK DATE]="")), 
            --(Table1[DPA] <> "Y"), --(Table1[Disbursement Date]=Daily!$E36),
            --(Table1[CLOSING DATE] > 1), --(Table1[Run Date] > E36), 
            --ISERROR(SEARCH("Jumbo", Table1[Loan Program])), 
              Table1[Total Loan Amount])
```

Any maths operation involving a boolean converts the boolean to 1 or 0. You didn't need the double unary at the beginning since you were adding three boolean results.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: It could also be written like `--(((T/F)+(T/F)+(T/F))>0)` but the SIGN function tidies everything up nicely and returns 1 or 0.